# How to remove system apps while building

Tags: android, porting, building

I was trying to remove system apps
Like latinime.apk , gallery.apk
I have removed in generic.mk but the  memory is not reducing.. Any help?

Comment: are the apks still present after your change?

Answer (score 0):

System apps can only be uninstalled if your device is rooted. If not?, you can use clean master app to free some space.

Comment: This question appears to be about building from sources, not uninstalling/deleting system apps.